# Upgraded from fc10 to fc12 now I have eth0_rename, how do I get back to plain old eth0?

Tags: linux, ethernet, fedora-12

I upgraded from Fedora 10 to Fedora 12. Unfortunately, my ethernet interface eth0 is now named eth0_rename. I'd like to get back to having it named plain old eth0.

I googled a bit but the solution of removing the eth0 entry from /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules seems to have no effect (I restarted the network service but didn't reboot).

The interface works just fine although I could see a script or two having a problem with the format. So, it's more of an inconvenience thing than anything else.

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to restart `udev` instead of your network service since it is the one taking care of device names (among many other things).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is...

remove the corresponding interface lines from /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules and then reboot your machine. Voila, simple eth0, etc interface names again.

I suppose I should have rebooted before asking the question but at least now the question and answer are here for others.

Comment: Nice it worked ;) So mark your own answer as right.

Comment: Since I posted it and answered it I have to wait a couple days before I can mark it as the answer. Don't want to artificially build myself up I guess. Thanks Honk.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when cloning a virtual machine.  Removing the rules didn't work.  However, updating the existing rules to match the new MAC addresses worked.  It tried to make new rules for the new interfaces, but it didn't recognize that the old interfaces were gone.  It's an ugly bug.